# Optimization function which return incorrect solution

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I have this function from a book. The goal is to generate random solution and evaluate the cost across the cost function.

My doubt is... why the function return the last solution `r` and not the `bestr` (the best solution)?

This code is pasted from [a repo of my book](https://github.com/arthur-e/Programming-Collective-Intelligence/blob/master/chapter5/optimization.py), programming collective intelligence (T.Seragan)

This function and parameters are generic ,and the costf is correctly

```
def randomoptimize(domain,costf):
  best=999999999
  bestr=None
  for i in range(0,1000):
    # Create a random solution
    r=[float(random.randint(domain[i][0],domain[i][1])) 
       for i in range(len(domain))]

    # Get the cost
    cost=costf(r)

    # Compare it to the best one so far
    if cost<best:
      best=cost
      bestr=r 
  return r
```

If I return `bestr`, the solution is best, but if I return `r` it's not. Tested with an example many times.

Comment: Sorry, mis-read the code at first. If this is exactly as it is in the book, then yes, it's probably a mistake by the author. However, note that also the indentation is off (the `return` and `cost=...` lines do not match any previous level of indentation).

Comment: I fixed the indentation based on the original code from the repo and also added the link; hope you don't mind.

Comment: this istruction make no sense ?-->for i in range(len(domain))]

Answer (score 1):

Good question! Without knowing the exact context, it looks like it should return `bestr` and that this is a bug in the code from your book.

Comment: This function is generic by design ...  Context is the file optimization.py and schedule.txt for the flight , but is only an application of genric optimiaztion algorithm

Comment: I appreciate that, I'm saying that you're right and the code should return `bestr` instead of `r`.

Comment: No, I mean a bug in the code from the book cited. I don't think fixing the indentation would help anyway would it?

Comment: @DuncanWP Sorry, mis-read the code. You might be right after all. But the indentation is wrong, too (look at the return).

Comment: because is very terrible identing python code on this forum(sorry for that , i am very newbie on this forum) , if you would help me , check optimization.py file here https://github.com/arthur-e/Programming-Collective-Intelligence/blob/master/chapter5/optimization.py ,but i guess the identation is correct

Comment: @Alex In the file, the indentation is right, although using two spaces is being frowned upon. You don't have to re-indent each line individually, just paste the entire block and then hit the `{}` button.